# Can performFetchWithCompletionHandler be used for non-network related fetches in iOS7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, background-process, core-motion, apple-m7

I know that performFetchWithCompletionHandler is intended to be used to fetch data in the background over the network, but could I use it to fetch data that does not require a network connection instead? For example, I want to pull some step count information form CoreMotion's step count query using the M7 motion co-processor. Would that be a legitimate use of this API or could Apple block my app for using the API to fetch non network data?

Comment: Sounds like this might be a question for apple developer support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Apple with this and they refused to answer my quesiton, however my app was approved using the technique I mentioned above, so I assume that using performFetchWithCompletionHandler in this way is allowed.